# How can I support overhanging Trex decking without adding more framing below?

Tags: deck

Alright I made a mistake...

We decided to add a frame to our approved deck plan, but the frame was made too wide and part of the deck boards (about 6") are hanging and not connected to the joist.

While I know adding extra blocking is an option, I wonder if there is a quicker way for the end-to-width connection without modifying the frame.

Thanks everyone!

[image: Deck end to width connection]

Comment: Not unless you like "bouncy."

Comment: Not really in this case :)

Comment: Then bite the bullet and block.

Comment: Someone has to post that as an answer. Since I'm fourth in line I'd rather not.

Comment: I put a short one in so we have one, but I'm not going to be upset if someone writes a longer one.

Comment: Accepted it thanks @KMJ.

Comment: And thanks @Huesmann. The bullet is bitten.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Add the framing. Even if you could fasten the ends to the crosswise board, you'll just end up with the composite board splitting at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Trex should be 12" on center and no more that 1" overhang.

Comment: Citation needed. I'm finding 16" centers and 4" (102mm) overhang.

Comment: @FredricShope -- citation needed. <g> I recently installed Trex decking, and the specification was 12"on center and no more than 1" overhang.

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't actually answer the question asked.

Answer (score -1):

Cut back 5-1/2" and add another picture frame boatd.